# Can someone trace me from mobile phone IP?

Tags: privacy, user-tracking

I have mobile phone, on which I am using internet. My phone number is registered under name of my employer, because they give you services like cheaper call fares, etc.

I also purchase internet balance using balance I get from my employer on phone.

Now I am interested is it possible my employer or mobile phone service provider relate my identity and browsing history?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42568/discussion-on-question-by-user200300-can-someone-trace-me-from-mobile-phone-ip). Please stop using comments for this sort of thing. If you have valid questions, first search to see if they have been answered here already (most of the ones you asked have) and are on topic (recommendations aren't) and then use the Ask a Question link

Answer (score 4):

There can be two cases while you're browsing :

1. Over HTTP :

   In this case all your traffic goes in plain-text format, hence if an ISP **wants** to keep track of browsing history, they can easily do that. But in most cases, ISPs doesn't care(unless Government force them to) about what you do with your internet package. But they surely can track you including the things you send to the sites, like passwords, files. And also can [impersonate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) to be one of the sites you want to visit.
2. Over HTTPS:

   Now when you visit the sites over HTTPS protocol, things get tricky for the ISPs and Government Agencies. Since HTTPS does the two important things :

   - Verify the source : the data being received is from the Original Source.
   - Protect the data : the data being transferred is encrypted, so that only sender and receiver knows what is going on. This includes the URL of the website.

   Since the connection is encrypted with at least 128-bit key. The ISPs can't see what you're browsing or what you're sending to those sites.

   But there is a catch, even though the data is encrypted it at-least needs a source and destination. Now the ISPs can see(if they want+care) the IP addresses you are visiting, and by IP address one can [roughly estimate](https://www.google.com/search?q=reverse%20ip%20lookup) the site you're trying to visit.

So, in order to keep the ISPs completely in dark, you need to use VPN while you're doing any online activity. In your case, you'll either need [L2TP/IPSec4 VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_2_Tunneling_Protocol) service, or use [VPNGate](http://www.vpngate.net/en/) with OpenVPN App([Android](http://www.vpngate.net/en/), [iOS](http://www.vpngate.net/en/)).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42566/discussion-on-answer-by-deepak-chaudhary-can-someone-trace-me-from-mobile-phone).

Answer (score 0):

## Yes and no.

- Location - easily traceable.
- Browsing history - not traceable
- Credit card - as long as the site is using HTTPS, no.

Anything transmitted over HTTPS using a secure certificate isn't traceable.

Give me time to write a more detailed answer later explaining why and how.